# How can I find (and fix) the cause of a circular dependency in a Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a Rakefile in which I am using `rake-compiler` to cross-compile a native extension for use on Windows using `rake cross native gem`. For some reason I have started to get a "Circular dependency detected" error, and the task fails. I have tried to track down the cause of this, but it's hard to follow the dependency graph of the dynamically generated tasks. Plus, this error only occurs when running under the `rake-compiler-dock` docker image, so I think the environment that `rake` is run under affects the dependency graph.

I also tried to use this [raketree.rb](https://gist.github.com/techiferous/416249) file that I found, but when I ran it with the `--dependency-tree` flag, it simply didn't output anything.

How can I find the cause of this problem?